# Single Tapping not being detected on dynamically created uibuttons

Tags: ios, dynamic, uiscrollview, uibutton, subclassing

It was necessary to create a subclass of UIButton, lets call it subButton. These subButtons are instantiated one by one and dynamically added to an UIScrollView object.

Unfortunately the subButtons aren't reacting as expected. After scrolling away from the first dynamic generated subButtons and then returning back to them. They loose their reactivity to single tapping. I can not explain this behaviour. Can somebody explain why its behaving this way?

Many thanks.

Source code

```
self.subButton = [[SubButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(69.5, y, 201, 114)];
[self.subButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
self.subButton.imageData = imageData;
self.subButton.videoPath = videoPath;
self.subButton.vidIndex = _indexVideo +1;
[self.subButton drawVidPreview];
[self.subButton setTag:(_indexVideo +1)];
[self.subButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.videoScroll addSubview:self.subButton];
[_videoPreviews addObject:self.subButton];
```

The subButton method drawVidPreview adds some subviews to itself.

Comment: Can you add the code of your buttons?

Answer (score 2):

Do the buttons not respond at all, or just not to single-tap? That might help us help you.

If they don't respond at all, I would check your view hierarchy to make sure no other view (perhaps invisible) are sitting above your buttons. Or, perhaps are the buttons not being added to the parent view you think?

Comment: Those are good questions. They actually react to single taps if I change the code to [self.subButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside]; But the response is too sensitive. It conflicts with the scrolling.

Comment: Yes I need both of the lines, most likely to the lack of knowledge in this respect. I don't know how to get the subviews of a UIScrollview object, thats why I add them to a NSMutableArray, to be able to modify their position on selection.

Comment: Maybe try: UIControlEventTouchDown see how that works for you.

Comment: Thanks, that was the one I actually meant, it did not work for me. As the one (UIControlEventTouchUpOutside) I accidentally wrote down.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are not adding the same `UIGestureRecognizer` instance to all of the `UIButtons`, instead for each `UIButton` you need to add a separate instance, however all gesture instance can point to the same target.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder, but this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

At last, i could solve the problem. The reason why the first subButtons did not respond to single tapping with UIControlEventTouchDown is because the uiScrollview content offset was set to a negative y value. This first of all was not necessary and was done out of pure laziness. I corrected it by giving it a positive value.

So my conclusion is, if you do not set the content offset or content size of the scrollView correctly, some dynamically added buttons to the scrollView might not respond to tapping appropriately. This is even the case if all Buttons are placed completely on a uiScrollview object.

This I could confirm by playing around with the content size of the uiScrollview instance too. I changed size of the y value of uiScrollviews instance just by few points and then some of the last buttons did not respond to tapping anymore.

Just by increasing the content size of the y value again, made the buttons responsive again.